# Node request throwing: Error: Invalid URI "www.urlworksinbrowser.com" or options.uri is a required argument

Tags: node.js, parsing, url, request, streams2

I'm using Node v0.10.11 on Ubuntu 12.04. I can't figure out what I'm missing to make streams of URLs work with the request module. 
This program is trying to go to a mailing list site, find the download links for each month, then download the pages for each month.

Mikael's readme says "The first argument can be either an url or an options object. The only required option is URI, all others are optional.
    uri || url - fully qualified uri or a parsed url object from url.parse()"

If I call `url.parse(www.targeturl.com)`, I get

```
Error: options.uri is a required argument
```

If I don't use `url.parse`, I get

```
Error: Invalid URI "www.freelists.org/archive/si-list/06-2013"
```

(this link works perfectly fine in my browsers)

I've cut the code down to 42 lines. Any advice welcome

```
var request = require('request'),
  url = require('url'),
  stream = require('stream'),
  cheerio = require('cheerio'), // a reduced jQuery style DOM library
  Transform = require('stream').Transform

var DomStripStream = function(target) {
  this.target = target;
  stream.Transform.call(this,{objectMode: true});
}

DomStripStream.prototype = Object.create(
  Transform.prototype, {constructor: {value: DomStripStream}} 
)

DomStripStream.prototype.write = function () {
  this._transform.apply(this, arguments);
};

DomStripStream.prototype.end = function () {
  this._transform.apply(this, arguments);
  this.emit("end");
};

DomStripStream.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
  chunk = chunk ? chunk.toString() : "";
  $ = cheerio.load(chunk);
  domLinks = $(this.target);
  $(domLinks).each(function (i, link) {
    currLink = 'www.freelists.org' + $(link).attr('href') 
//  currLink = url.parse(currLink)
    request(currLink, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  });
}

var fs = require("fs"),
  output = fs.createWriteStream("out.txt"),
  mainPage = new DomStripStream('td a')

request('http://www.freelists.org/archive/si-list').
pipe(mainPage).
pipe(output);
```

Comment: Give http:// or https:// in the url

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add http:// or https:// in the url

Comment: ummm, how do we show the root of the URL?  I know the path, but the root differs if I am in development or production...so it will be http://{root}/path....I can't just pass it http://path....

Comment: Check `document.location`, it contains the `protocol` field. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location)